# Order Items in List by object's object.property lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public class Object1
{
    public List<Object2> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    DateTime aDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to set the order of a

```
List<Object1>
```

according to the newest Object2 item in Object1.Logs .
How can I do that properly in shorthand with lambda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to order your list in ascending order then you can select the minimum date from the inner list and then use that in `OrderBy` like:

```
var orderedQuery = list.OrderBy(r => r.Logs
                                    .Min(t => t.aDate));
```

*Just make sure to make your property `aDate` `public`, otherwise it will not be visible outside the class.*

In case you are looking to get the latest values first then you need `Max` instead of `Min` to select the latest date from the inner list, and use `OrderByDescending` if you want that particular order.

You can also add check for checking against `Empty` and `null` something on the lines of:

```
var orderedQuery = list.OrderBy(r => (r.Logs != null && r.Logs.Any()) ? 
                                        r.Logs.Max(t => t.aDate) 
                                        : DateTime.MinValue);
```

Comment: I would think that newest would mean the the latest value and thus you should use `Max`.

Comment: @juharr, nice catch, I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Also add some check for an empty `Logs` list, otherwise you know, exception etc :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - Since `Min` and `Max` are Linq extension methods (Not instance methods), you don't need to check for null.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I didn't mean null, but empty. `Min` and `Max` are known to throw in such case.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I am pretty sure you have to check for `null` , since the extension method are defined in a way to throw exception in case of `ArgumentNull`,

Comment: So for example we have: `List<Object1> list = new List<Object1> { new Object1 { Logs = null } };  var orderedQuery2 = list.OrderBy(r => r.Logs.Min(t => t.aDate)).ToList();` We will get Null Reference Exception at `Min`

Comment: I believe if the sequence is empty `Min` and `Max` return the default value of the type.

Comment: @juharr, yes that is true. It just if the sequence is `null`, there is NRE

Comment: @Habib Actually `ArgumentNullException`, not NRE since it's an extension method.

Comment: Nope It looks like it only returns the default value if the type is a reference type or a nullable.  Otherwise it does throw if the sequence is empty.

Comment: For value types collection, it does throw "Sequence contains no elements"

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Object1>();

/* add your Object1 objects here */

list = list.OrderByDescending(c => c.Logs.Max(d => d.aDate)).ToList();
```